# Why these Two Queries performace so different?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0, performance-tuning, query-performance

**This is Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
    A.innings_no AS Inn, bowler, OT.Out_Name AS OutType, Runs
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.innings_no, a.striker, SUM(b.runs_scored) AS Runs
    FROM
        ball_by_ball a
    INNER JOIN batsman_scored b USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        b.match_id = 981018
    GROUP BY a.innings_no , a.striker , striker_batting_position) AS A
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        w.player_out, kind_out, fielders, bowler
    FROM
        wicket_taken w
    INNER JOIN ball_by_ball a USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        a.match_id = 981018) AS B ON (striker) = (player_out)
        LEFT JOIN
    Out_Type OT ON B.kind_out = OT.Out_Id;
```

**Explain:**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
    | id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key        | key_len | ref                                                               | rows | filtered | Extra           |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                     | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                                              |  240 |   100.00 | NULL            |
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | w          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Ball_Id,Innings_No,Over_Id,Player_Out                                                                                                                                            | Player_Out | 8       | A.striker,const                                                   |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index           | PRIMARY    | 16      | const,database.w.over_id,database.w.ball_id,database.w.innings_no |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
    |  1 | PRIMARY     | OT         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.w.kind_out                                               |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | a          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index           | PRIMARY    | 4       | const                                                             |  240 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
    |  2 | DERIVED     | b          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Batsman_Scored_Ball_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Over_Id_index | PRIMARY    | 16      | const,database.a.over_id,database.a.ball_id,database.a.innings_no |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
    +----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

**Visual Explain:**
[image: query one visual explain]

**This is Query 2:**

```
SELECT
  A.innings_no AS Inn,
  bowler,
  OT.Out_Name AS OutType,
  Runs
FROM
  (SELECT
     a.innings_no,
          striker_batting_position,
     a.striker,
     SUM(b.runs_scored) AS Runs
   FROM
     ball_by_ball a
       INNER JOIN batsman_scored b USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
   WHERE
       b.match_id = 981018
   GROUP BY a.innings_no , a.striker, striker_batting_position) AS A
    LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
          innings_no,
          striker_batting_position,
     w.player_out, kind_out, fielders, bowler
   FROM
     wicket_taken w
       INNER JOIN ball_by_ball a USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
   WHERE
       a.match_id = 981018) AS B  on (A.innings_no,A.striker_batting_position)=(B.innings_no,B.striker_batting_position)
    LEFT JOIN
  Out_Type OT ON B.kind_out = OT.Out_Id;
```

**Explain:**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key     | key_len | ref                                                               | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                              |  240 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | w          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Ball_Id,Innings_No,Over_Id                                                                                                                                                       | PRIMARY | 4       | const                                                             |   11 |   100.00 | Using where     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index           | PRIMARY | 16      | const,database.w.over_id,database.w.ball_id,A.innings_no          |    1 |   100.00 | Using where     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | OT         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY | 4       | database.w.kind_out                                               |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  2 | DERIVED     | a          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index           | PRIMARY | 4       | const                                                             |  240 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
|  2 | DERIVED     | b          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Batsman_Scored_Ball_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Over_Id_index | PRIMARY | 16      | const,database.a.over_id,database.a.ball_id,database.a.innings_no |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

**Visual Explain:**
[image: query two visual explain]

> This two query has only one difference which is `joining clause` where
>   the first query has `B ON (striker) = (player_out)` and second has `B 
>   on
>   (A.innings_no,A.striker_batting_position)=(B.innings_no,B.striker_batting_position)`
>   but if you look at the **Visual Explain** you will notice that First
>   Query **Rows Count is 240 and Query Cost is 633.62** but Second Query
>   **Rows Count is 2.80K and Query Cost is 4597.15**. Also First Query **Examined 557 Rows** and Second Query **Examined 987 Rows**.

**What is the reason of this type performance? Are not first query efficient than second one? Please someone explain it, I'm unable to find out the reason.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Row constructors" are handled, but *not* efficiently.  Sample `WHERE` (or `ON`) clauses:

```
WHERE a = b   -- good

WHERE (x,y) = (p,q)  -- bad (row constructors)

WHERE x = p AND y = q  -- good (same semantics as above, but better performing)
```

(5.7.3 improves the performance.)

Comment: is that rules apply for only where clause? because after change the code `on (A.innings_no,A.striker_batting_position)=(B.innings_no,B.striker_batting_position)` to `on A.innings_no=B.innings_no and A.striker_batting_position=B.striker_batting_position` the explain result is same. as here i'm using sub query it's not possible to create combined index for those two row. so, please can you tell me how can i make that query efficient?

Comment: I would expect `ON` and `WHERE` to act the same.  In many situations, `EXPLAIN` fails to give enough details to clearly spell out what will happen.  Sometimes this provides more info:  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: thanks @Rick, i am trying to understand `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and maybe will learn soon but please can you look at my that question? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235206/why-subquery-do-not-filter-the-result-in-multiple-subquery