# Why Subquery do not filter the result in multiple Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-8.0

**This is Query (skipped selection for simplicity and also it work perfect):**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.striker
    FROM
        ball_by_ball a
    LEFT JOIN batsman_scored b USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        b.match_id = 981018
    GROUP BY a.innings_no , a.striker) AS A
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        w.player_out
    FROM
        wicket_taken w
    INNER JOIN ball_by_ball a USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        a.match_id = 981018) AS B ON striker = player_out
;
```

> There are two Subquery as `A` and `B`. As my thinking Subquery A will be executed first and than do filtered the result by grouping, thus `Rows` will be reduced and than Subquery B will be joined with those `Rows`. But that not happening see below.

**This is that Query Visual Explain:**
[image: Query Visual Explain]

> If you notice the Visual Explain there `Subquey A` executed but it did not filtered the `Rows`, it returned all `240Rows`. If i execute that Query alone it returned `19Rows`. This is really a big problem because for it **My Query Cost Increased Huge.**

**Look at below Visual Explain:**
[image]

> This work what i wanted and what i explained for `Subquery A` but only when i use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. As i need `LEFT JOIN` so that not going to work because i need all `Rows` from `Subquery A`, I tried `Right JOIN` that's result also same as `LEFT JOIN`.

**Now i want to know how can i make my query more efficient as i mentioned first, like second visual explain?**

### UPDATED WITH COMPLETE QUERY AND TABLES STRUCTURE

**My Original Query (The purpose of this Query is to showing Batsmans Score):**

```
SELECT 
    A.*, kind_out, fielders, bowler
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.innings_no,
            a.striker,
            SUM(b.runs_scored) AS Runs,
            COUNT(*) AS Balls,
            SUM(IF(b.runs_scored = 0, 1, 0)) AS Zero,
            SUM(IF(b.runs_scored = 4, 1, 0)) AS Fours,
            SUM(IF(b.runs_scored = 6, 1, 0)) AS Sixes
    FROM
        ball_by_ball a
    LEFT JOIN batsman_scored b USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        b.match_id = 981018
    GROUP BY a.innings_no , a.striker) AS A
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        w.player_out, kind_out, fielders, bowler
    FROM
        wicket_taken w
    INNER JOIN ball_by_ball a USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        a.match_id = 981018) AS B ON striker = player_out;
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+---------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
| innings_no | striker | Runs | Balls | Zero | Fours | Sixes | kind_out | fielders | bowler |
+------------+---------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
|          1 |     254 |    4 |     6 |    5 |     1 |     0 |        1 |      162 |    140 |
|          2 |     162 |    9 |    12 |    9 |     2 |     0 |        2 |     NULL |     80 |
|          1 |       2 |    1 |     4 |    3 |     0 |     0 |        1 |      110 |    140 |
|          2 |       8 |    0 |     2 |    2 |     0 |     0 |        2 |     NULL |     80 |
|          2 |     110 |   79 |    47 |   10 |     5 |     5 |     NULL |     NULL |   NULL |
|          1 |      88 |   26 |    30 |   11 |     2 |     0 |        2 |     NULL |    434 |
|          1 |      21 |    1 |     9 |    8 |     0 |     0 |        1 |      270 |     32 |
|          2 |     354 |    0 |     1 |    1 |     0 |     0 |        1 |      147 |     80 |
|          2 |      32 |    1 |     6 |    5 |     0 |     0 |        1 |      147 |     35 |
|          1 |     147 |   73 |    41 |   13 |     5 |     6 |        1 |        8 |    382 |
|          2 |     369 |    0 |     3 |    3 |     0 |     0 |        1 |      186 |     80 |
|          2 |     255 |   21 |    15 |    6 |     2 |     1 |        4 |     NULL |     35 |
|          2 |     140 |   33 |    25 |    8 |     3 |     1 |     NULL |     NULL |   NULL |
|          1 |      35 |    3 |     7 |    4 |     0 |     0 |        1 |      162 |     32 |
|          1 |      71 |    8 |     6 |    1 |     1 |     0 |        2 |     NULL |     32 |
|          1 |     433 |   19 |     9 |    3 |     1 |     2 |        1 |        8 |     32 |
|          1 |      80 |   10 |     4 |    0 |     2 |     0 |        3 |      369 |    434 |
|          1 |      14 |    1 |     2 |    1 |     0 |     0 |        2 |     NULL |    434 |
|          1 |     186 |    1 |     2 |    1 |     0 |     0 |     NULL |     NULL |   NULL |
+------------+---------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
19 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Table Structure `BALL_BY_BALL`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ball_by_ball` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `over_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ball_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `innings_no` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `team_batting` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_bowling` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `striker_batting_position` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `striker` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `non_striker` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bowler` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index` (`ball_id`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index` (`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index` (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index` (`match_id`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index` (`over_id`),
  KEY `Bowler` (`bowler`),
  KEY `Non_Striker` (`non_striker`),
  KEY `Striker` (`striker`),
  KEY `Team_Batting` (`team_batting`),
  KEY `Team_Bowling` (`team_bowling`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`non_striker`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`striker`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `match` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`team_batting`) REFERENCES `Team` (`Team_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`team_bowling`) REFERENCES `Team` (`Team_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`bowler`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table Structure `BATSMAN_SCORED`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `batsman_scored` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `over_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ball_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `innings_no` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `runs_scored` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Ball_Id_index` (`ball_id`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Innings_No_index` (`innings_no`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index` (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_index` (`match_id`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Over_Id_index` (`over_id`),
  KEY `Runs_Scored` (`runs_scored`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`over_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`over_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ball_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`ball_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`innings_no`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`innings_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table Structure `WICKET_TAKEN`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wicket_taken` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `over_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ball_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `innings_no` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `player_out` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kind_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `fielders` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_Id` (`ball_id`),
  KEY `Fielders` (`fielders`),
  KEY `Innings_No` (`innings_no`),
  KEY `Kind_Out` (`kind_out`),
  KEY `Over_Id` (`over_id`),
  KEY `Player_Out` (`player_out`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`player_out`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_13` FOREIGN KEY (`over_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`over_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_14` FOREIGN KEY (`fielders`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_15` FOREIGN KEY (`ball_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`ball_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_19` FOREIGN KEY (`kind_out`) REFERENCES `Out_Type` (`Out_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`innings_no`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`innings_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

### MORE INFO ADDED AS OTHER MEMBERS SUGGESTION:

**This is my Original Query Visual Explain:**
[image]

**This is my Original Query Explain:**

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key        | key_len | ref                                                               | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                     | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                                              |  240 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | P          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Player_Id_index                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY    | 4       | A.striker                                                         |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pm         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Id                                                                                                                                                                        | PRIMARY    | 8       | const,A.striker                                                   |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | w          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Ball_Id,Fielders,Innings_No,Kind_Out,Over_Id,Player_Out                                                                                                                          | Player_Out | 8       | A.striker,const                                                   |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index,Bowler    | PRIMARY    | 16      | const,database.w.over_id,database.w.ball_id,database.w.innings_no |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | OT         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.w.kind_out                                               |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | p1         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Player_Id_index                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.w.fielders                                               |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | P2         | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Player_Id_index                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.a.bowler                                                 |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  2 | DERIVED     | a          | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index,Striker   | PRIMARY    | 4       | const                                                             |  240 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
|  2 | DERIVED     | b          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Batsman_Scored_Ball_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Over_Id_index | PRIMARY    | 16      | const,database.a.over_id,database.a.ball_id,database.a.innings_no |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
10 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**This is my Original Query Statistic:**
[image]

**This is the Query According to Rick James Suggestion:**

```
SELECT 
    a.innings_no,
    p.Player_Name AS Batsman,
    SUM(b.runs_scored) AS Runs,
    COUNT(*) AS Balls,
    SUM(IF(b.runs_scored = 0, 1, 0)) AS Zero,
    SUM(IF(b.runs_scored = 4, 1, 0)) AS Fours,
    SUM(IF(b.runs_scored = 6, 1, 0)) AS Sixes,
    (SUM(b.runs_scored) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS SR,
    CASE pm.role_id
        WHEN 1 THEN '(c)'
        WHEN 2 THEN '(wk)'
        WHEN 4 THEN '(c & wk)'
    END AS Role,
    OT.Out_Name AS OutType,
    p1.Player_Name AS Filder,
    p2.Player_Name AS Bowler
FROM
    ball_by_ball a
        LEFT JOIN
    wicket_taken w ON w.match_id = a.match_id
        AND a.striker = w.player_out
        LEFT JOIN
    ball_by_ball a1 ON a1.match_id = w.match_id
        AND a1.over_id = w.over_id
        AND a1.ball_id = w.ball_id
        AND a1.innings_no = w.innings_no
        INNER JOIN
    batsman_scored b ON b.match_id = a.match_id
        AND b.over_id = a.over_id
        AND b.ball_id = a.ball_id
        AND b.innings_no = a.innings_no
        LEFT JOIN
    Out_Type OT ON kind_out = OT.Out_Id
        LEFT JOIN
    Player p1 ON fielders = p1.Player_Id
        LEFT JOIN
    Player p2 ON a1.bowler = p2.Player_Id
        INNER JOIN
    Player p ON p.Player_Id = a.striker
        LEFT JOIN
    player_match pm ON pm.match_id = 981018
        AND pm.player_id = a.striker
WHERE
    a.match_id = 981018
GROUP BY a.striker , a.innings_no , OT.Out_Name , p1.Player_Name , p2.Player_Name;
```

**This is Query Visual Explain:**
[image]

**This is Query Explain:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                            | key        | key_len | ref                                                                             | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Batsman_Scored_Ball_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_index,Batsman_Scored_Over_Id_index | PRIMARY    | 4       | const                                                                           |  231 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index,Striker   | PRIMARY    | 16      | const,database.b.over_id,database.b.ball_id,database.b.innings_no               |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | w     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,Player_Out                                                                                                                                                                       | Player_Out | 8       | database.a.striker,const                                                        |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a1    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index,Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index,Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index           | PRIMARY    | 16      | database.w.match_id,database.w.over_id,database.w.ball_id,database.w.innings_no |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pm    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Id                                                                                                                                                                        | PRIMARY    | 8       | const,database.a.striker                                                        |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | OT    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.w.kind_out                                                             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p1    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Player_Id_index                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.w.fielders                                                             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Player_Id_index                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.a1.bowler                                                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Player_Player_Id_index                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.a.striker                                                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
9 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

**This is Query Statistic:**
[image]

> If you see *Query Statistic* there Original Query (Which is using
>   Sub-queries) `ROW Examined is 615` Rick James Suggested Query (Which
>   is flatten Query) `ROW Examined is 1661`. **So that is really
>   confusing that which Query is Efficient**.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. First, does this query return the results you want or not?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yeah the query work perfect but i think it's not efficient as it takes huge cost.

Comment: Does it need to be `LEFT`?  Can you flatten the query into a 4-way `JOIN`?

Comment: @RickJames yeah that need to be left because always `Subquery A Result` will be greater than `Subquey B Result`, so must need to get all `Rows` from `Subquery A`. What you means 4-way `JOIN`? i can join those tables as single query but that make my query cost and row examined more higher than this.

Comment: *As my thinking Subquery A will be executed first* No. This order affects only on subqueries results scan order.

Comment: OK. Please add the table definitions (of all 
3 tables) ie the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;`

Comment: @Akina i updated my Question with details information, please look my question once again it maybe clear now, my main intention is to make my `QUERY` more efficient.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ i updated my Question with details information, please look my question once again it maybe clear now, my main intention is to make my `QUERY` more efficient.

Comment: Is the newly added "Output" correct?  That is, is your Question about optimization?  If the Output is incorrect, what should it say?  (Sometimes we can work backward -- construct a query that delivers the desired output.)

Comment: @RickJames my output is correct, i'm just looking for optimization. if i can learn one query optimization it will help me further query optimization.

Comment: @RickJames it maybe not optimization because optimization maybe means indexing. I'm looking for **Low Row Process and Low Cost Using**.

Comment: @Rhidoy - Providing the optimal `INDEX` is _one_ form of optimization, perhaps the _main_ form.

Comment: @Rhidoy - I made another stab; see my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames - Sorry for late Response, i was not online. Please see my Question again, in the bottom i added what your suggestion previously. i added both two query (my query and as your suggested query) explain, visual explain and status.

Comment: @Rhidoy - You weren't online?  Sleeping _is_ allowed.

Comment: @RickJames :) i means out of internet network. :)

Comment: @Rhidoy - One fewer temp table _may_ explain the difference.  A temp table probably implies writing rows to it and rereading them.  Another way to get some insight into what happened during a query is discussed [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts).

Comment: @RickJames well after summing up handler read_first, read_key, read_last, read_next, read_prev, read_rnd, read_rnd_next i found subquery took 23640 and flatten query took 22771 rows respectively. it means flatten took few index?

Comment: @Rhidoy - Sum up `Handler_writes` to get a clue of temp table activity.  The two read numbers are close enough so that I would not draw a conclusion about the difference.  The numbers do not distinguish between index and data hits.  Nor do they give clues of whether the I/O had to be performed.  Still, there exact numbers, not estimates, as found in `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92958/discussion-between-rhidoy-and-rick-james).

Comment: As far now i may use any of those query because my indexing are good and also those query are not slow or don't have performance effect. Although, I just try to know how to write more efficient query (i'm not database admin) and i think as far now i'm done. Thanks for your valueable time, i made your question as answer so it may help others.

Comment: Programmers can _and should_  learn optimization techniques.  Tossing a performance problem 'over the wall to the DBA' is not a good way to split duties.

Comment: @RickJames- thanks for your valueable advice. I will start learn more on MySQL. Actually i'm a student and this is my learning project, that's why thought i learn enough for this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am lost as to the intent of the query -- partially because of not knowing the game.)

Here's an attempt at flattening it:

```
SELECT  bb1.striker, w.player_out
    FROM  ball_by_ball bb1
    LEFT JOIN  wicket_taken w  ON w.match_id = bb1.match_id
      AND  bb1.striker = w.player_out
    JOIN  batsman_scored bs
       ON  bs.match_id = bb1.match_id
      AND  bs.over_id = bb1.over_id
      AND  bs.ball_id = bb1.ball_id
      AND  bs.innings_no = bb1.innings_no
    JOIN  ball_by_ball bb2
       ON  bb2.match_id = w.match_id
      AND  bb2.over_id = w.over_id
      AND  bb2.ball_id = w.ball_id
      AND  bb2.innings_no = w.innings_no
    WHERE  bb1.match_id = 981018
```

Indexes (the order of columns mostly does not matter):

```
wicket_taken:    (match_id, player_out, kind_out, fielders)
batsman_scored:  (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no, runs_scored)
ball_by_ball:    (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no, bowler)  -- match_id first
```

It might help if you provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

**More comments**

Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `JOIN` is needed.  (Eg, the first derived table).

Please tag these with what table(s) they are in:  `kind_out, fielders, bowler`.

I added more columns to my suggested indexes -- to (hopefully) make them "covering".

Could you provide the old fashoned `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: i updated my Question with details information, please look my question once again. now i'm testing your query but there not need second `ball_by_ball` table, one can do the work, i used two for `Subquery`.

Comment: One more question does MySQL keep table order as i write in my Query?

Comment: Thnx, much better now! I will try to answer later today

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you most welcome, i will be thankful to you for your time.

Comment: @Rhidoy - The Optimizer is free to look at tables in any order.  (`LEFT JOIN` that can't be turned into `JOIN` is an exception.)  The Optimizer usually uses the `WHERE` clause to pick the table that will be filtered the most as the first table.

Comment: @RickJames thank your so much for your value able times but actually i'm really confused about MySQL efficient Query because i'm totally new here. So still i'm searching which way my Query will be efficient. As here i used `Subquery` and you used `Flattening`. but when i checked `EXPLAIN` from MySQL Workbench i found that **`Flattening` examined more `ROW` than `Subquery` but the Query Cost seems same**. So which Query Should i used? Is there any way to open a chat here so i can sent you details or may i create a new question with details about those two query and put the link here?

Comment: @Rhidoy - Usually I try to rewrite a query such that it provides the identical output, but I suspect that I failed in this case.  So, take my query as a suggestion of how to structure this thing, rather than using subqueries.  It _may_ end up being faster.  (Again, I cannot be sure.)  [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) are some basic tips on indexing for optmization; however it does not get into subqueries much.

Comment: well, so Flattening is good to use? I checked this link and my indexing is fine. Actually where i'm puzzled is that **What does MySQL Workbench Row Examine Means**. Is it tell how many Rows it check to complete the Query or how many Rows it process to compete the Query. Example: There have 16Rows From Table A and MySQL check those 16Row 2Times With Table B 1Row and C 1Row. So what will it tell? 16+16*1+16*1=48 or 16+1+1=18?

Comment: @Rhidoy - `Workbench` is a UI in front of other tools -- `EXPLAIN` provides an _estimated_ number of rows to be examined for each table.  _Sometimes_ the right math is to _multiply_ the 'Rows' values together.  The 'Visual' version is even harder for me to interpret.

Comment: @Rhidoy - Subqueries often (but _not always_) optimize poorly.  Optimization is rarely an issue for hundreds of rows; how many seconds is the query taking?

Comment: @RickJames Flattening took `0.144s` and Subquery took `0.009s` as Workbench Server Response Time but those time change per execution. Example when i run Subquery second time it took `0.122s`

Comment: @Rhidoy - Did the flattened version give the 'correct' results?  If you had to modify what I suggested, please add it to your Question so we can discuss it further.  Someone suggested you did not need ball_by_ball twice -- have you acted on that?